# Example of an open set $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and a point $a\in \mathbb{R}^n\setminus A$ which is an isolated point of $\partial A$

Tags: general-topology

Could someone give me an example of an open set $A\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and a point $a\in \mathbb{R}^n\setminus A$ such that $a$ is an isolated point of the boundary of $A$?

Comment: Well, one can be boring and take the empty set. Then $\partial \varnothing=\varnothing$. Every point in $\varnothing$ is an isolated point.

Comment: No one has explicitly mentioned the simplest example: $A=\Bbb R^n\setminus\{x\}$, where $x$ is any point of $\Bbb R^n$.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try $A=\{x:0<\|x\|<1\}$.

Comment: One can take any open (connected?) set with an interior point removed, yes?

Comment: Of course, @PeterTamaroff, or any discrete set of interior points. I'm not sure why connectedness is relevant.

Comment: Nifty solution!

Comment: Are there any solutions for $n>1$ where the boundary point is not an isolated point of $\Bbb R^n\setminus A$? I'm guessing no?

Comment: @dfeuer: I believe your guess is spot on. If $x\notin A$ is an isolated point of $\partial A$, then doesn't this mean there is a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ so that $U-\{x\}\subset A$?